# Is there a rule for when to pronounce "ah" instead of "ae" in RP versus GA?

Tags: pronunciation, rules, received-pronunciation

I would like to know if there is a rule when to pronounce ah in RP versus ae in GA.
Is it a question of vocabulary or is there a rule for that?

Examples:
dance- in RP is pronounced ah 
but in GA  it is pronounced ae

or: can't, romance, cast, fast, etc.

Comment: The difference between RP and GA is that RP has the bath-trap split (answered in the second duplicate)

Comment: It's not that simple.  RP speakers pronounce 'stand' with a short A [it's a native word] but 'command' with a long A [it's borrowed from French, so pronounced in a kind-of-French way.  Having said that, RP generally pronounces 'answer' with a long A although it's definitely of OE origin, but this morning I heard George Osborne [UK Chancellor of the Exchequer and undoubtedly posh] say it with a short A.  So the rule is, there's no rule.